# Clone a DataBound Checked List Box

Tags: c#, .net, clone, checkedlistbox

I have a DataBound CheckedListBox, I "check" few items on list box(source), then I need to clone it to new Checked List Box(target). It need to have all the data, with checked state. I have tried with following function. It is properly flowing through this function.

But finally I can see items on target CheckedListBox  but none of the items in target is checked.

```
 private void CloneCheckedListBox(CheckedListBox source, CheckedListBox target)
    {            
        foreach (int checkedItemIndex in source.CheckedIndices)
        {
            target.SetItemChecked(checkedItemIndex, true);
        }
    }
```

Edit:

I have a User control which I have placed on a TabPage, on that User Control there is a  "CheckedListBox", I do need to create a new TabPage with the user entered value on selected(current) TabPage(on User Control)

So, what I have done is, create a new Tab Page, get a Copy of the User Control calling it's "Clone()" method.

In "Clone()" method need to have CheckedListBox cloning feature.

Here is my Cloning Code, which is on User Control...

```
 public SearchMain Clone()
    {
        SearchMain smClone = new SearchMain();
        smClone.txtManufacturers.Text = this.txtManufacturers.Text;
        smClone.udPriceFrom.Value = this.udPriceFrom.Value;
        smClone.udPriceTo.Value = this.udPriceTo.Value;
        smClone.chkOld.Checked = this.chkOld.Checked;
        smClone.chkPrx.Checked = this.chkPrx.Checked;
        smClone.chkDisc.Checked = this.chkDisc.Checked;
        smClone.chkStock.Checked = this.chkStock.Checked;
        smClone.chkFirstDes.Checked = this.chkFirstDes.Checked;
        smClone.chkFirstPN.Checked = this.chkFirstPN.Checked;
        smClone.txtSuppPN.Text = this.txtSuppPN.Text;
        smClone.txtManuPN.Text = this.txtManuPN.Text;
        smClone.txtManufacturers.Text = this.txtManufacturers.Text;
        smClone.meDesAND.Text = this.meDesAND.Text;
        smClone.meDesOR.Text = this.meDesOR.Text;
        smClone.meDesNOT.Text = this.meDesNOT.Text;
        smClone.lbManufacSelected.Items.AddRange(this.lbManufacSelected.Items);
        smClone.lbSearchWithIn.Items.AddRange(this.lbSearchWithIn.Items);
        **CloneCheckedListBox(this.clbLang, smClone.clbLang);**
       // CloneCheckedListBox(this.clbTypes, smClone.clbTypes);
        return smClone;
    }
```

Comment: So tell us what you tried. The operation is rather trivial.

Comment: Where do you copy the actual items from one to the other?

Comment: Show us some more code, so we know what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see correct answere here..

[Programatically Checking DataBound CheckListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654056/programatically-checking-databound-checklistbox)

Answer (score 0):

try set

```
source.DataSource = target.DataSource;
target.DisplayMember = "YourDisplayItem";
target.ValueMember = "YourValueItem";
foreach (int checkedItemIndex in source.CheckedIndices)
{
     target.SetItemChecked(checkedItemIndex, true);
}
```

Comment: As I explained in my question I am getting values, but they are not checked as in the "source"