# Programmatically Checking DataBound CheckListBox

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox, databound

I have a DataBound "CheckedListBox", I need to check some items on it. I tried with following code...

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Languages))
        {
            string[] langs = search.Languages.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < (langs.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < clbLang.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    string lng = clbLang.Items[j] as string;
                    if (lng.Trim() == langs[i])
                    {
                        clbLang.SetItemChecked(j, true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

No errors, debuged execution is going through "*checking*" process, but finally I cannot see anything checked on it.

Then I have added a button and added following code to it. (*upon click check all the items*)

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clbLang.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            clbLang.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
```

It is "*checking*" all the items, Please tell me if anyone can see a issue here...?

Comment: You _need_ to name your buttons.

Comment: Ouch!  Please use `foreach(string lang in langs)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < (langs.Length - 1); i++)`.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, it is used only for testing...

Comment: @Phaedrus I do DataBind while loading the form.

Comment: At what point are you calling your 'checking' code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out, it is a **Bug** introduced by MS.

It is well explained here.

> The issue is easy to reproduce. Just hide and show a databound
>   CheckedListBox and you will notice how
>   the previously checked items get
>   unchecked.

[CheckedListBox SetItemChecked method not working](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/msg/6e1ad9489333572f?hl=en)

So we have to find a workaround... I tried follwing way, it is working nice...

At the place where I was calling *checking* of items I have added following... I am adding what I need to check in **Tag** of the control.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Languages))
{
    clbLang.Tag = search.Languages;
}
```

Then, following code in that control's "VisibleChanged()" event.

```
private void clbLang_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lngs = clbLang.Tag as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lngs))
        {
            string[] langs = lngs.Split(',');
            foreach (string lang in langs)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (DataRowView row in clbLang.Items)
                {
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        string lng = row[1] as string;
                        if (lng.Trim() == lang)
                        {
                            clbLang.SetItemChecked(j, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works well with me, hope it will benefit you...

Comment: You should report the bug on MS Connect.